# mySQL statement not working inside of php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Im trying to do a login system for my website and I changed around how it is implemented and it broke, whenever I try to login with a correct login it fails to take me to the next page, here is my php:

```
<?php
//finds the correct database
$sql_link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root" , "12buckle", "GameData");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to databse: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_POST['Username']))
{
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);
//checking to see if password and username can be found in student database
//loading in correct data
$login = mysqli_query($sql_link,"SELECT * FROM tblStudents WHERE    UserName='$username' AND Password='$password'");
if ($login['Password'])
{
    $_SESSION['name'] = $login['StudentFirstName'];
    $_SESSION['ClassID'] = $login['ClassID'];
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $login['StudentID'];
    header ("Location: index.php");
}
else
{
$login = mysqli_query($sql_link,"SELECT * FROM tblTeacher WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password'");
if ($login['Password'])
{
    $_SESSION['name'] = $login['TeacherSurname'];
    $_SESSION['title'] = $login['Title'];
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $login['TeacherID'];
    header ("Location: TeacherSide.php");
}
else
{
echo 'Login details incorrect';
}
}
}
```

Also if it helps when I ran it last night im sure it worked, but I was half awake so I may have been testing the old version

Comment: you have fetch the data before using them.

Comment: then mysql_real_escape_string() should be changed to mysqli_real_escape_string($sql_link,postdata)..

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is faulty. `mysql_query` returns a result HANDLE. it does not return any actual data. You need to fetch a row first, before checking for actual data:

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql_link, "SELECT * FROM tblStduents ....");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   ... got a student record
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo $row['StudentFirstName'];
} else {
   ... no student rows, repeat with teachers
}
```

Comment: I am still having the same issue with the update, not sure if I am implementing it correctly.

Comment: And if its useful this information is inside a html file and the values $username and $password are coming from a form in the file

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues in the past where variables aren't read properly the way you have them in your SQL statements.

Try `Username='" . $username . "' AND` instead and see what happens.